# Can you iteratively create uniquie variables in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, loops, arraylist

In VB.Net I am attempting to create multiple variables iteratively and dynamically based on a list. I have created a List(Of Double) that (depending on another variable) contains x number of Double. Assume that I have already declared Dim varList As List(Of Double), and that I have filled the list with a few values. If, for example, List.Count = 5, I want to:

```
    Dim ListCount As Integer = varList.Count
    Do While ListCount > 0
        Dim Var(ListCount) As Double = varList(ListCount) ' THIS IS MY PROBLEM
        Console.WriteLine("Variable created called Var{0}", ListCount)
        ListCount = ListCount - 1
    Loop
```

And so on until Var1. You'll notice I specifically call out the line of code that doesn't work "THIS IS MY PROBLEM" because VB.NET doesn't work that way. If I could get it working, the console output would look something like...

```
Variable created called Var5
Variable created called Var4
Variable created called Var3
Variable created called Var2
Variable created called Var1
```

"Dim" seems to be a statement with an annoyingly limited capability. Regardless, you can see a full example of what I am trying to do here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dJQJOq

Comment: Why not just use an array? Var(1), Var(2), etc. are separate variables.

Comment: You could use List(of

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do with this hypothetical dynamic `Var[n]`?  There is almost certainly a reasonable way to represent it; possibly a list, possibly an array, possibly a single appropriately-named variable inside a loop.